# Holoviews scatterplot is giving empty plot

Tags: python, plotly-dash, holoviews

I am trying to create a scatter plot with a DataFrame. But holoviews scatter function is giving me empty plot without any data points. I am using Plotly Dash to plot the graph.

Below is my code:

```
    df = pd.read_parquet('data/part.0.parquet')
    print(df.head())      ### gives correct shape of dataset
    
    dataset = hv.Dataset(df)
    print(dataset)       ### gives :Dataset

    scatter = hv.Scatter(dataset, kdims=["col1"], vdims=["col2"])
    
    components = to_dash(app, [scatter])

    app.layout = html.Div(components.children)
```

Comment: It's hard to debug anything without a reproducible example. E.g. here we can't tell whether "col1" and "col2" are actually columns in your df and have non-empty values, and thus whether we'd expect a non-empty plot in the first place. In any case there doesn't seem to be a reason to create `dataset` in this case; just use `hv.Scatter(df, ...)`. And reading `data/part.0.parquet` directly instead of `data` is not typical usage for a Parquet directory. But neither of those issues would presumably cause an empty plot, if there is actually data in the df.

Comment: There is data in the file. I printed it using df.head() and all the columns with data is there but still when I use the scatter plot it is empty. If I remove the kdims parameter, I get First letter of each column name as x-axis and second letter as y-axis. This is very strange behaviour.

Comment: Again, not practical to debug unless we have a reproducible example.

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar I've uploaded the data and code here. https://github.com/anu0012/dash-holoview-example